# MediaRecorder access denied "android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA", fails at Start() though I have all permissions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, video-capture, mediarecorder

Been trying to sort this for past week, I have a simple android application which im trying to get to record a video using the devices camera and the 'MediaRecorder' I get the same result whether I test on an emulator (Android 11) or a real device (s22 ultra)

Everything is prepared but start() always returns 'failed to start'. In device logs I can see one of the first error logs is to do with access denied "android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA", even though I have included this in the manifest aswell as "android.permission.CAMERA". I also have android.hardware.camera.any permission.
Any help in resolving the issue would be great all solutions on here dont seem to work.
I have also tried using Plugin.Permissions which shows that I do have the Camera permission granted.

UPDATE: Im thinking these issues may be caused by not implementing a 'camera preview' surface. I have viewed the mediarecorder docs and I do everything sequence now but I dont set a preview (because I dont understand how to implement in xamarin forms).

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Media;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using RECOmobile.Models;
using RECOmobile.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Core;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

private async void Take_Video_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await checkCameraPermission();

        var outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myvideooutputfile.mp4");
        //string filePath = "/data/data/Example_WorkingWithAudio.Example_WorkingWithAudio/files/testAudio.mp4";
        string filePath = "/data/data/com.companyname.recomobile/files/myvideooutputfile.mp4";
        //correctCamera();
        //if (camera != null)

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        System.IO.File.Create(filePath);

        if (recorder == null)
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(); // Initial state.
        else
            recorder.Reset();

        Camera c = null;
        try
        {
            c = Camera.Open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c.Unlock();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }

        recorder.SetCamera(c);
        recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Camcorder);
        recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);

        //recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        //mediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(1280, 720);
        //recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
        //recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);




        CamcorderProfile camProf = CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.Q720p);
        recorder.SetProfile(camProf);
        recorder.SetOutputFile(filePath);
        //recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        recorder.Prepare();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        try
        {
            recorder.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
        }



    }
```

Device error logs:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
10-10 14:27:48.874  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 539 AlarmManager    Alarms must either supply a PendingIntent or an AlarmReceiver
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 Camera2-Parameters  Error finding static metadata entry 'android.distortionCorrection.availableModes' (1b0001)
10-10 14:27:54.342  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 302 HwBinder:302_3  type=1400 audit(0.0:1783): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1073 scontext=u:r:hal_camera_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-10 14:27:54.347  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.347  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 libc    Access denied finding property "ro.camera.res.fmq.size"
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 libc    Access denied finding property "ro.camera.req.fmq.size"
10-10 14:27:54.338  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2ClientBase   Camera 0: Opened. Client: com.companyname.recomobile (PID 437, UID 10156)
10-10 14:27:54.338  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 CameraService   disconnect: Disconnected client for camera 0 for PID 437
10-10 14:27:54.336  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera3-Device  disconnectImpl: X
10-10 14:27:54.306  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera3-Device  disconnectImpl: E
10-10 14:27:54.295  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 Camera2Client   notifyError: Error condition 0 reported by HAL, requestId -1
10-10 14:27:54.295  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 CameraService   CameraService::connect evicting conflicting client for camera ID 0
10-10 14:27:54.293  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 CameraService   CameraService::connect call (PID 19443 "com.companyname.recomobile", camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 411 ServiceManager  Permission failure: android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA from uid=1013 pid=437
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder Using default video fps 30
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 MPEG4Writer PreAllocation enabled
10-10 14:27:50.991  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:50.991  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 chatty  uid=1000(system) Binder:539_2 identical 1 line
10-10 14:27:50.990  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:50.990  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 SoundTriggerMiddlewareLogging   setCaptureState[this=com.android.server.soundtrigger_middleware.SoundTriggerMiddlewareImpl@d9fa08f, caller=1041/331](false)
10-10 14:27:50.787  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder stop while neither recording nor paused
10-10 14:27:50.787  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 331 AudioFlinger    session id 201 not found for pid 19443
10-10 14:27:50.777  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   447 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   Destruction - bufferpool2 0x7b03df1d0068 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 1, 0% recycled; transfers: 0, 0% unfetched
10-10 14:27:50.776  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   447 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   bufferpool2 0x7b03df1d0068 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/1 (recycle/alloc) - 0/0 (fetch/transfer)
10-10 14:27:50.775  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   Destruction - bufferpool2 0xe58c6628 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 5, 0% recycled; transfers: 0, 0% unfetched
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Verbose 447 C2Store unloading dll
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   bufferpool2 0xe58c6628 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 0/0 (fetch/transfer)
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Verbose 447 C2Store in ~ComponentModule
10-10 14:27:50.773  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 hw-BpHwBinder   onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
10-10 14:27:50.772  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 CCodecBufferChannel [c2.android.amrnb.encoder#143] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
10-10 14:27:50.772  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 chatty  uid=1013(media) codec_looper identical 2 lines
10-10 14:27:50.771  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 CCodecBufferChannel [c2.android.amrnb.encoder#143] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder stop while neither recording nor paused
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder Failed to set stopTime 5757715322 us for Audio
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 AMessage    failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
10-10 14:27:49.656  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   539 WifiNative  Scan result ready event
10-10 14:27:49.656  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   539 WifiNl80211Manager  Scan result ready event
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2-Parameters  Camera 0: Disabling ZSL mode
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2-Parameters  initialize: allowZslMode: 0 slowJpegMode 0
10-10 14:27:54.342  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 302 HwBinder:302_3  type=1400 audit(0.0:1784): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1073 scontext=u:r:hal_camera_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-10 14:27:54.365  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 OMXClient   IOmx service obtained
10-10 14:27:54.366  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    442 OMXMaster   makeComponentInstance(OMX.google.h264.encoder) in android.hardwar process
10-10 14:27:54.368  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 MediaCodec  MediaCodec will operate in async mode
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 OMXUtils    do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  setupAVCEncoderParameters with [profile: Baseline] [level: Level41]
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  [OMX.google.h264.encoder] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring.
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  [OMX.google.h264.encoder] cannot encode HDR static metadata. Ignoring.
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  setupVideoEncoder succeeded
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance setConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 OMXUtils    do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance getConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigLatency(0x6f800005)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.370  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance getConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.374  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 ResourceManagerService  Ignoring request to add new resource entry with value <= 0
10-10 14:27:54.376  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   442 SoftAVCEnc  Params width 176 height 144 level 41 colorFormat 0
10-10 14:27:54.380  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    331 AudioFlinger    AudioFlinger's thread 0x79c44956a040 tid=19677 ready to run
10-10 14:27:54.382  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:54.383  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 chatty  uid=1000(system) Binder:539_2 identical 1 line
10-10 14:27:54.384  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:54.386  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 AudioRecord createRecord_l(62): Server adjusted notificationFrames from 1024 to 122 for frameCount 2048
```

Comment: Do not hardcode paths...

Comment: is that causing the issue? I have used an enviroment path before (OutputPath) also @Selvin

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no data/data/package path... There is a user in path for some time

Comment: I agree not to hardcode paths. However ```/data/data/<package>/files/...``` is a proper path. So that's not the point.

Comment: if I put an incorrect path the app will error before start() at System.IO.File.Exists( no? @Selvin

Comment: Could you show how you declared the permission?

Comment: the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#capture-video) describe a considerably more complex workflow required to record video

Comment: @Jason have updated the question with the correct sequence of code still returning the same error. BUT i am not setting a preview as I cannot figure out how to create a surface view in xamarin forms